# FusedLocationProviderClient and Wakelocks

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location, android-wake-lock, jobintentservice

I am implementing a solution to track location updates in my Application,both in foreground and background, and perform some task when location is updated.

As per the Google recommendations in https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent), I used PendingIntent variant of requestLocationUpdates API.

What is the best way to perform a task when location is changed ?

As per the Google sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent, task to be performed when location changes, is done in the onReceive() of broadcast receiver. This approach doesn't deal with wakelocks and the device background restrictions.

As per my understanding after going through various stackoverflow answers and different blogs, I have to use JobIntentService.

1. Is using JobIntentService is the correct approach for my requirement
2. Do Application needs to acquire wakelock to perform a task when location changes, when device is in sleep mode(I am aware that JobIntentService automatically handles wakelocks).
3. When the system callbacks like onlocationChanged(),onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver() are invoked, is CPU awaked automatically when device is in sleepmode. If waked, how much time it will be active ? Does it wait for callback to be finished.

Answer (score 1):

Found some useful info in Android source code comments

"When location callbacks are invoked, the system will hold a wakelock
on your application's behalf for some period of time, but not
indefinitely. If your application requires a long running wakelock
within the location callback, you should acquire it yourself."

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/LocationManager.java

**Is using JobIntentService is the correct approach for my requirement**

Using JobIntentService would be the correct approach,
 1. It can handle wakelocks,
 2. As there are background limitaions on Android "O" and above versions, it can work in Maitainance window of doze mode.

**Do Application needs to acquire wakelock to perform a task when location changes, when device is in sleep mode(I am aware that JobIntentService automatically handles wakelocks).**

Location change callbacks come with wakelocks acquired and loose if callback is returned. For any lengthy task in callbacks, Service has to be started in callback with wakelocks(JobIntentService would help here).

**When the system callbacks like onlocationChanged(),onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver() are invoked, is CPU awaked automatically when device is in sleepmode. If waked, how much time it will be active ? Does it wait for callback to be finished.**

System callbacks often come with wakelocks acquired, and release when callback is returned. As they run in UI main thread, any task to be done has to be offloaded to service. For services to run even in device sleep usecase, wakelocks have to be acquired, and again JonIntentService helps here.

JobIntentservice also deals with doze mode in a best possible manner.

Note: Because of the background location restrictions, to get the continuous location updates, App has to start the foreground service.